# Where do I ask questions about software structure?

Tags: discussion, scope

One of the bullet points for this site is that it is not for asking, "Higher-level architecture and design of software systems".

That's exactly what I'm needing answers about. If not here then where?

Specifically, I'm asking how to implement a certain feature. Not so much the code but what it's expected behavior should be.

Comment: "Not so much the code but what it's expected behavior should be." I am wondering if maybe you might be interested in [UX.StackExchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would be [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

> Programmers Stack Exchange is a Q&A site for professionals and students in software development and related fields who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development.
>
> If you have a question about...
>
> - software requirements
> - **software architecture and design**
> - algorithm and data structure concepts
> - quality assurance and testing
> - **development methodologies and processes**
> - software configuration management
> - software engineering management
> - software licensing
>
> https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic